# Single-value loss/training in a CNN with a tensor output

Tags: training, tensorflow, python, keras, objective-functions

I am playing around with an idea of using using Q-learning with a DQN (Deep Q-Network), to determine the optimal position of a number of 'units' on a grid of allowed locations, according to some reward-metric that is only calculated after placing all of the units. I am following much of [Deep Convolutional Q-Learning with Python and TensorFlow 2.0](https://rubikscode.net/2019/07/22/deep-convolutional-q-learning-with-python-and-tensorflow-2-0/), but I diverge with the grid output.

To do this, I use a CNN that takes in a one-hot encoded grid of the units (`0=no units here`, `1=one unit here`), and outputs a grid with the same shape as the input with expected rewards of placing a unit at this location.

I can use the following Tensorflow/Keras code to get the expected rewards, where units can be placed in 3 dimensions and channels determining the different unit-styles:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

model = models.Sequential(name="DQN")
model.add(
    layers.Conv3D(
        filters=10,
        kernel_size=3,
        activation="relu",
        padding="same",
        input_shape=input_shape,
        bias_initializer="random_normal"
    )
)
model.add(layers.Conv3D(filters=10, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(layers.Conv3D(filters=input_shape[-1], kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding="same"))

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=tf.keras.losses.Huber(), metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Currently I am using a very simple training scheme, where Q-values are first generated from the current state. At the position where the agent earlier placed a unit, the calculated true reward is given and trained against.
If the following state was a terminated state, the calculated reward is used directly, while the discounted reward is used in non-terminated states.

```
for state, action, next_state, reward, terminated in minibatch:
    # state: one-hot grid
    # action: index in the state where a unit is placed by the agent
    # terminated: True/False whether the 'next_state' is the terminated state

    q_target = model.predict(state)

    if terminated:
        q_target[0][action] = reward
    else:
        following_target = model.predict(next_state)
        q_target[0][action] = reward + gamma * np.amax(following_target)

    model.fit(state, q_target, epochs=1, verbose=0)
```

This means, that only a single value in the entire training tensor is the true reward - all other are approximated by the CNN.
However, all of the expected rewards are used in training, instead of this singular value. So I was considering whether it would be possible to train the CNN towards this single value only, and whether it would make any sense at all?

I thought of creating a custom loss function that would calculate the loss function for this single action, so training is done against this. However, I can't really figure out how I would go about doing this. I've looked at something like [Custom training with tf.distribute.Strategy](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/custom_training), but I wasn't successful at it..